# how to use/implement navigation drawer-like feature for older versions of android

Tags: android, design-patterns, navigationcontroller

http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html

I need this functionality, like gmail,linkedin,youtube app but that should support also older versions of android like 2.3

Comment: try a sliding menu if that is what you want https://github.com/athulh/SlidingMenu

Comment: sliding menu gives me an exception unable to instantiate activity component ExampleListActivity

Answer (score 0):

[SherlockNavigationDrawer](https://github.com/nicolasjafelle/SherlockNavigationDrawer) is probably the way to go, as I reckon you might want to combine it with [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com) as well.

That said, [SlidingMenu by Athulh](https://github.com/athulh/SlidingMenu) works both with and without `ActionBarSherlock`, so that's another option. :)

Comment: I have yet to try one of them myself, but from what I'm guessing - both work, but `SherlockNavigationDrawer` explicitly states this in the readme. :-)